# How to extract items from excel dropdown?

Tags: excel, office-2016

I have xls file with many dropdowns that contains large numbers of items (elements in collection) and I would like to have them copied in text editor.

[image]

Any idea or information will be helpful for me.

Comment: The list will already exist in your workbook. Click the cell with the dropdown. Then in the Excel Top Ribbon, got to the `Data` tab > Then Click `Data Validation` > The box entitled `Source` will tell you which sheet and which cells contain this list (it may be a hidden sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Open the workbook that you want the list from, paste this into a new module and run it (<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>→<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>→<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>→<kbd>F5</kbd>).  It loops through controls and lists dropdown in a text file (in the same path as the workbook) and opens it in Notepad.

```
Sub ListAllCombos()
'loop through active workbook: sheets -> shapes -> dropdowns -> input ranges
Dim ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape, c As Range, r As Range
Dim x As Integer, strOut As String
strOut = "   Workbook Name: " & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & vbCrLf
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    strOut = strOut & "--Worksheet Name: " & ws.Name & vbCrLf
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.FormControlType = xlDropDown Then
            x = x + 1
            strOut = strOut & "--DropDown Name: " & shp.Name & vbCrLf
            Set r = Range(shp.ControlFormat.ListFillRange)
            For Each c In r
                strOut = strOut & Worksheets(ws.Name).Range(c.Address) & vbCrLf
            Next c
            strOut = strOut & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next shp
Next ws

If x = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No dropdowns."
    Exit Sub
End If
strOut = strOut & "(" & x & " dropdowns)" & vbCrLf

'write to text file & open in Notepad
Dim fName, RetVal
fName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\DropDowns (" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & ").txt"
If Dir(fName) <> "" Then If MsgBox("Existing file will be replaced.", vbOKCancel, "Replace") = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
Open fName For Output As #1
Write #1, strOut & vbCrLf & Now()
Close #1
If MsgBox("File created:" & vbCrLf & x & " listboxes saved in file: " & fName, vbOKCancel, "Open list in Notepad?") = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
RetVal = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\Notepad.EXE " & fName, 1)
'Debug.Print strOut
End Sub
```